# Is there a trick to making Google Docs that are generated by Forms searchable?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a GAS script to generate Google Docs from a Google Form that members in my domain submit. Everything works great - email notifications are delivered, a folder is generated and the Doc is nested inside - however, even though everything is placed in a folder that is shared to the domain that most users have already added to their Drives, the issue is that the Doc cannot be found via search in Google Drive until a user manually edits the document and it autosaves. I'm using the line:

```
docPerms.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access), setting **Access** to **Domain** makes Docs "findable" by everyone in the domain but for my domain it requires an additional manual open and auto-save to become "searchable". Has anybody else encountered this or found a solution?

So far, I tried programmatically concatenating a space to the end of the doc (which I do manually now) but that didn't fix it.

Comment: i believe it must be on each user's drive. one way to achi6 that is to also add the new folders to a single common folders that all users have added to their drive.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but we already have a shared common folder in place, I'll update the original post. Most of our users have the common folder added to their drives and new docs still aren't searchable.

Answer (score 0):

I [submitted a similar issue to Google](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1841) just over 3 years ago. In my case the document is generated from apps script.